# ¿Cómo hago que fscanf deje de leer?

Tags: c

Me dejaron de tarea hacer un programa en C que gestione publicaciones y éstas sean leídas de un archivo de texto. Originalmente, para la carga había puesto`fscanf(archivo Publicaciones,"%[^\n]s",publicacion);` pero me imprimía cosas raras, por lo cual se me ocurrió añadir, al final de cada publicación, un texto que me indique el final `<eop>` con sprintf. Pero no sé cómo hacer que lo encuentre.

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor Emilio, es importante saber lo que tratas de realizar, incluso agrega como esta estructurado el archivo que tratas de leer, revisa [ask]. Por otra parte me parece que tal vez necesitarías usar fgets() para leer toda la linea completa de tu arhico

Comment: Esto puede ser porque tu archivo puede que no contenga saltos de linea. El parametro "%[^\n]s" indica que leer hasta conseguir salto de linea, y como el caracter fin de archivo no es lo mismo al salto de linea continua leyendo

Comment: Si estas en un bucle: Puede que lees y cuando llega la ultima linea no se detiene de leer

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `fscanf` con el parámetro `"%[^\n]s"` lee hasta conseguir un salto de linea o un carácter `\n`. Esto significa que si el archivo no tiene salto de linea, `fscanf` leerá lo que consiga y como ya paso el fin de archivo lee cualquier cosa que este en ese contiguo referente al archivo en la memoria.

Una solución puede ser usar `fgets` o `fgetc`:

```C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILE_NAME "./you file name.txt"
int main(void){
  char line_1[301];
  char line_2[301];
  FILE* f=fopen(FILE_NAME,"r");
  //fgets:
  fgets(line_1,300,f);//Leemos una linea o hasta que llegue a una cantidad de 300 caracteres.
  //fgetc:
  int i=0;
  for (;i<300 && (line_2[i]=fgetc(f))!=EOF && line_2[i]!='\n';i++);
  line_2[i]='\0';//Para indicar el final de la cadena.
  print("Linea 1 es: %s",line_1);
  print("Linea 2 es: %s\n",line_2);
  print("Fin");
  return 0;
}
```

La primera no tiene mucha ciencia, solo uso `fgets` para leer una linea o hasta que llegue al carácter numero `300` del archivo `f`.

La segunda uso un bucle `for` para leer el archivo donde:

- `i<300`: Todavía hay espacio en el `buffer` para almacenar la linea.

y

- `(line_2[i]=fgetc(f))!=EOF` : No es fin de archivo.

y

- `line_2[i]!='\n'` : No es salto de linea.

#### Lecturas recomendadas

- [fscanf - doc](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/#:%7E:text=some%20library%20implementations.-,%5B%5Echaracters,-%5D)
- [fgetc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc)
- [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)